# Uploading CSV file to Google Drive

Tags: python

I'm still relatively new to Python and the only reason that I am learning it is because of the competition that my department having. And I fell in love with it immediately.

My question is how to upload csv file to Google Drive from PyCharm.

I'd made some research that there is a package for that, which is PyDrive. But so far, all the examples that I read has nothing to do with uploading an existing file from my desktop to a Drive that I created for the csv file. Maybe there is a way but my beginner's brain still isn't familiar with it. You can share example code if you have it or if you have relevant document for me to read, I would be very thankful too.

However, my lecturer showed that using Google Colab would be easier. Therefore, if there is really no solution to my question, "To upload csv file to Google Drive from PyCharm", I would use Google Colab instead.

That's all.
Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is related to Python, Pycharm is just the IDE and has nothing to do with the actual code. It could apply as well to VS, or any IDE of your choice. I have suggested an edit which better reflects your question.

Comment: I don't think you know how to research documentation. Here's the link from the official documentation explaining how do upload with Python. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#python

Answer (score 1):

Using [PyDrive](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filemanagement.html#upload-a-new-file):

```
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

# Create GoogleDrive instance with authenticated GoogleAuth instance.
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# Create GoogleDriveFile instance with title 'Hello.txt'.
file = drive.CreateFile()
file.SetContentFile("path/to/your_file.png")
file.Upload() # Upload the file.
print('title: %s, id: %s' % (file['title'], file['id']))
```

The related part of the doc is [this one](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filemanagement.html#upload-and-update-file-content).

Comment: Thank you! It still doesn't work actually, but after I read the doc and tweak the my code a little bit, it works!

Answer (score 0):

or you can use it like that:

```
import httplib2
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

page_token = None
http = httplib2.Http()
scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secrets.json', scope)
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', http=credentials.authorize(http))
file_metadata = {
    'name': 'file.csv',
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.file'
}

media = MediaFileUpload('file.csv',
                        mimetype='application/vnd.google-apps.file',
                        resumable=True)
created = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                       media_body=media,
                                       fields='id').execute()

print('File ID: {}'.format(created.get('id')))
```

where **client_secrets.json** is authentication file generated, while creation service account.